# How to expand array values stored as properties in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a property bag (json object) that unfortunately has an array of objects by dynamically named properties, rather than an actual array. There are other properties in the bag as well. For example:

```
{
  "something": "whatever",
  "another": "doesn't matter",
  "thing1": "value1",
  "thing2": "value2",
  "thing3": "value3"
}
```

Ultimately I'd like to have one row per `thing`:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

I know I can use `mv-expand` to convert an array or property bag into multiple rows, but I'm not sure how to

1. Keep only the properties where key starts with "thing"
2. Discard the key, keeping only the value

In case it's important, the number of things per property bag varies greatly. Usually it's only one, but sometimes it's 10-20 and rarely it could be 100 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try using `mv-apply` for that:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({"something":"whatever","another":"doesn'tmatter","thing1":"value1","thing2":"value2","thing3":"value3"}),
    dynamic({"somethingelse":"whatever2","another":"doesn'tmatter2","thing1":"value12","thing2":"value22","thing3":"value32"}),
]
| mv-apply d on (
    extend key = tostring(bag_keys(d)[0])
    | where key startswith "thing"
    | project value = d[key]
)
```

which returns:

```
| value   |
|---------|
| value1  |
| value2  |
| value3  |
| value12 |
| value22 |
| value32 |
```